# "along the road" vs "alongside the road"

Tags: prepositions

This "**along**" and "**alongside**" will drive me crazy, because examples are just the opposite of what we are taught.

On the Cambridge dictionary, I have seen the sentence:

- [New pedestrian pathways are being built alongside the road](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alongside).

I have been studying "**along**" and "**alongside**", and I have learnt that thin, long places like road, rivers, paths, beaches etc should be followed by "**along**" because it means "*towards the end of something long in a line*".

So, in the above sentence, we understand that pedestrian pathways are being built, which means that the pathways should start from the start of the road, in parallel to the road, and continue until the end of it, which perfectly requires the preposition "**along**". But why does the sentence have "**alongside**" and not "**along**"?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that "*along the road*" means "*in a line next to the road along its extent*" whereas "alongside the road" means "*next to the road along its extent*".

Notice also that "*along the road*" is often understood as "*down/up, or on the road*" which can be confusing sometimes.

To unambiguously say is using "**along**" we should include **side/sides**:

- *New pedestrian pathways are being built **along the sides of the road***.

Comment: what is the difference between  "in a line next to the road along its extent"  and ""next to the road along its extent". They are completely same to me. Both of them refer to something starting from the start of the road and continue until end of the road in a long line just like the road itself, or like a second road in parallel to the road in question. May be that is why I can't understand the difference.

Comment: Where else would they be? Along the top? The bottom?